# WinForms: ImageList for ListView with different image sizes

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, imagelist

I have a `ListView` with `View` property set to `LargeIcon`. And I have an `ImageList` as image source for `ListView`.

What I want is to display both vertically and horizontally oriented images in `ListView` but `ImageList` have only a single property `ImageSize` for all images in its collection so for example if I set that property to 150x100 and add a vertical image (100x150) to collection - `ListView` automatically stretches it to 150x100.

So as I understand I need some `ImageList`, in which every image is stored with its original size. Any thoughts about how to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this problem myself, Here is what I did, I hope it will help you as well, first determine the biggest image size you would use ( for example 200x200) then use Png or Gif images (all 200x200) with transparent backgrounds.

have a look at these two images i have created as an example.

[image: this is the original 64x64 image file]

but I make it like this to avoid stretching:

[image: this is the 200x200 image file that have lots of transparent area]

Comment: Yeah, I've thought about that, but it seemed pretty ugly solution to me.. though it seems that I haven't much choise here :) Thanks anyway.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiaba can you help with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206339/listview-with-multiple-imagelist-and-icons-image

Answer (score 0):

To keep from stretching you can use cross-multiplication.

```
  Image Width       Desired Width
 --------------- = ---------------
  Image Height       New Height
```

or

```
  Image Width       New Width
--------------- = ---------------
 Image Height       Desired Height
```

In code it looks something like this

```
int height = img.Width*newWidth/image.Height;
```

or

```
int height = img.Width/image.Height*newWidth;
```

and

```
int width = img.Height*newHeight/image.Width;
```

or

```
int width = img.Height/image.Width*newHeight;
```

Then when creating your new bitmap you can draw a scaled image on the new bitmap using the desired size and the derived size.