# listview with multiple imagelist and icons/image

Tags: .net, listview, vb6, thumbnails, imagelist

i need a way to use two imagelist on a listview. one of the image list if for header icons which contain 16x16 icons, and another will contains 32x32 thumbnail pictures within the sub items.

The image below shows what am trying to do

[image: listview with hearder icons and thumbnail]

Comment: Try a different listview if it helps: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView

Comment: Will it be written in vb6 or .net (your tags could cause confusion)?

Comment: well my preference is in vb6, but i hear its possible using vb.net controls in vb6 twithout the .net framework? please advise on my best option

Comment: @nawfal is it possible to use .net controls in vb6

Comment: @Smith I'm not sure about it. I guess no. You make it another question to get more insight.

Comment: hello, sorry for the late response as I had a terrible week. you can do the same thing, use 32x32 images for headers use images that only 16x16 of them is the image you want and the rest would be transparent

Comment: AshkanMobayenKhiabani i tried to load both 32 an 16 images in an  imagelist but all images where forced to 16. and displayed as such. whats the work around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a trick which solves the issue. the trick is to create a 16x16 icon on a 32x32 canvas and center it. this is because the thumbnail size is 32bit max.
so i have one image list for 16pix isonc and another for 32pix icons

when thumbnail is needed, i only need to set the small icons to 32pix.

this support built it i only had to do this

```
' for the header columns
Set ListView1.ColumnHeaderIcons = ImageList1
' for the items and sub items
Set ListView1.SmallIcons = ImageList2
```

thanks for all your inputs

Comment: +1 for centering an smaller image in a larger image with transparent background.