# ListView ImageList set size for each image in C#

Tags: c#, image, size

I have a `ImageList` with images in different sizes. But when I bind the `Imagelist` to my `ListView` the image will strech to the `ImageList.Size`

Is it possible to set the size for each image in the `ImageList`?

Kind regards

---

C#(.NET 4.6.1) with Visual Studio 2017

Comment: No, they all will have the same size. When loading them into the imagelist they get stretched and/or color-reduced.  If you have only a few sizes you could use a few ImageLists. Otherwise a List<Image> is called for and for storage maybe resources.. To display them in the LView you will need ownerdrawing.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8365366/1132334